# Need to grab Amazon S3 sections from ip-ranges file

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab ip's from site below I was able to get whole site with python beautiful soup and use python regex module to just get the ip4 address
but I have ran into a issue I just need the ipv4 ip's were in section it says "S3" any help would be much appreciated

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

```
akamai_feed = urlopen('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json').read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(akamai_feed, 'html.parser')
ip_addr = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\b', soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feed is Json file, so you could use `json` module from Python standard lib:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

akamai_feed = json.loads( urlopen('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json').read() )

for prefix in akamai_feed['prefixes']:
    if prefix['service'] == 'S3':
        print(prefix['ip_prefix'])
```

Prints:

```
...

52.95.163.0/24
52.95.145.0/24
52.92.40.0/21
52.219.32.0/21
52.95.136.0/23
52.219.62.0/23
52.95.175.0/24

... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

The website contains a nested dictionary as JSON, so you need to read that JSON data first:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import json
>>> akamai_feed = urllib.request.urlopen('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json').read()
>>> akamai_json = json.loads(akamai_feed)
```

Now that you have the actual data, you can sift through using e.g. the [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda _: _['service'] == 'S3', akamai_json['prefixes']))
[{'ip_prefix': '52.95.154.0/23', 'region': 'eu-west-3', 'service': 'S3'}, {'ip_prefix': '52.219.64.0/22', 'region': 'ap-south-1', 'service': 'S3'}, ...]
```

This gives you a list of dictionaries whose `'service'` is `'S3'`. Alternatively, you can also use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [_ for _ in json.loads(akamai_feed)['prefixes'] if _['service'] == 'S3']
[{'ip_prefix': '52.95.154.0/23', 'region': 'eu-west-3', 'service': 'S3'}, {'ip_prefix': '52.219.64.0/22', 'region': 'ap-south-1', 'service': 'S3'}, ...]
```

If you’re interested in the IP addresses only, then…

```
>>> [_['ip_prefix'][:-3] for _ in json.loads(akamai_feed)['prefixes'] if _['service'] == 'S3']
['52.95.154.0', '52.219.64.0', ...]
```

If the `/xx` can be any number of digits or if the IP addresses are formats other than IPv4 strings then a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) will help to filter the string.

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression is unnecessary here because the IPs may not require validation, if I understand the problem right, we just want to get `"ip_prefix"` value, yet if you wish to do that with a regular expression, this might suffice:

```
"ip_prefix": "(.+?)"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LwbRN1/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\"ip_prefix\": \"(.+?)\""

test_str = ("{\n"
    "  \"syncToken\": \"1560279544\",\n"
    "  \"createDate\": \"2019-06-11-18-59-04\",\n"
    "  \"prefixes\": [\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"18.208.0.0/13\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-east-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.95.245.0/24\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-east-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.194.0.0/15\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"ap-northeast-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"54.155.0.0/16\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"eu-west-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"54.196.0.0/15\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-east-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"99.78.170.0/23\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"ap-southeast-2\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.94.22.0/24\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-gov-east-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.95.255.112/28\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-west-2\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"13.210.0.0/15\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"ap-southeast-2\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.94.17.0/24\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"eu-central-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.95.154.0/23\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"eu-west-3\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"52.95.212.0/22\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"ap-southeast-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"54.239.0.240/28\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"eu-west-2\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"54.241.0.0/16\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-west-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"184.169.128.0/17\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-west-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n"
    "    },\n"
    "    {\n"
    "      \"ip_prefix\": \"216.182.224.0/21\",\n"
    "      \"region\": \"us-east-1\",\n"
    "      \"service\": \"AMAZON\"\n\n"
    "...")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```